# Uninstall ARR components installed manually

Tags: uninstall, iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I installed ARR (Application Request Routing) manually on my 2012R2 server.

Now I want to remove its components :

- URL Rewrite Module
- Microsoft Application request routing 3.0
- Microsoft External Cache Version 1
- Microsoft web farm framework

But when I use control panel -> uninstall, I got this error :

```
Setup failed to detect shared configuration.
```

How can I bypass this ?

I precise that I've just removed IIS from my server.

Feel free to tell me if I'm not at the right place to ask this question. Maybe 'serverfault.SE' is better ? If so, can you please move my question or help me how to do this. TIA

EDIT : When I launch WPI (Web Platform Installer), and search 'routing', its telling me that Request Routing is installed ... but I uninstalled IIS ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wooo ! I just solved this.

I search for 'arr' then for 'rewrite' starting from 'C:\', etc. I deleted dirs in :

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers
```

I deleted `inetsrv` in `System32` and `inetpub` in `C:\`

And then, I could uninstall modules...

HTH